# Remove the cornerview tableview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, tableview

[tableview] [android] Anyone know how to remove the cornerview from this tableview plugin https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

I have tried to set an empty view

```
  override fun onCreateCornerView(): View {
       // return LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.tableview_corner_layout, null, false)
        return View(mContext)
    }
```

I don't want the cornerview to show at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with row header to not be visible either, try this:

```
mTableView.rowHeaderWidth = 0;
```